# Entity Framework: Call a stored procedure without mapping

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Is there a way to use stored procedures without using the Entity Framework function mapping, which is great but is a complete load of rubbish when any changes are added to the stored procedure, I am aware you can refresh the stored procedure mapping but it's just not efficient. Most of the time when you update your mappings it does not pick up the changes which is extremely annoying.

so far I have tried the following:

```
 var List = db.ExecuteStoreQuery<Business_Voucher_Top5_Result1>("exec usp_BusinessVoucher_Top5");
```

this works great but can I do it without creating the mapping and pass parameters to it?

Thanks

Comment: I agree with your rubbish comment. I've experienced the same thing and I laughed at our common frustration. ;)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to create mapping for `ExecuteStoreQuery` - you just need to use a type which has properties with same names as columns in the result set.