# Entity Framework - Calling A Stored Procedure Without Mapping

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, entity-framework-5

I currently use a database-first approach using Entity Framework (EF). I'm investigating different ways of calling stored procedures (stored procedures that are NOT tied to entities) using EF. Currently, I'm using the approach [found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb896231(v=vs.100).aspx) using the designer (in this approach, I import a stored procedure, create a function import and use a complex type as my mapped object). I don't like this because it relies on a bloated EDMX file and it causes merge conflicts in source control when two or more people perform this procedure and check in their code.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11684660/entity-framework-call-a-stored-procedure-without-mapping) which claims I can call a stored procedure and map to a plain old C# object (POCO).

My question is if I want to map to a POCO to a stored procedure in EF not using the designer approach, how do I get aliases for column names? For example, let's say I call a stored procedure and get a particular column back named "CustomerID" and I want the property mapped to it to be named "Id" instead of "CustomerID". How can I do this without using the designer approach?

Comment: As soon as you want to do anything complicated you'll need to access `context.Database.Connection.CreateCommand()` and essentailly get at the underlying ADO.Net. This way you can use Table Valued Parameters and Multiple Result Sets. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.database(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: I did something like this in ADO.NET. I created a POCO, decorated the properties that needed aliases with a custom AliasAttribute and used a SqlDataReader to iterate through the properties to match them to the columns in the result set. This resulted in an n*m operation and was much slower than EF. If I use the CreateCommand method, what would you suggest I do? I'm not familiar with EF at this deep of a level and not sure where to look to implement custom mapping like I did with ADO.NET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the following should work:

```
[your db context].Database.SqlQuery<[your POCO class]>("[name of stored proc] [comma separated parameters]", parameter1, parameter2, .....)
```

Here's example from one of my applications:

```
_context.Database.SqlQuery<Library>("usp_paged_select_libraries @userId, @offset, @fetch",                    userIdParameter, offsetParameter, fetchParameter);
```

Within your POCO you would mark up your properties with:

```
[Column("[your alias here]")]
```

Comment: I tried doing this and the property in my POCO with the Column attribute is not populating. I'm using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.Column. Am I missing anything?

Comment: I'm using EF 5 by the way. Is this for EF 6?

Comment: Hmmm, I did a little reading and it appears that the SqlQuery method does not honor the Column attribute. Given that, if you really do not want to have a class which mimics the columns in the stored proc you "could" create a separate POCO that does have 1 to 1 mapping of columns to properties and then use it when calling SqlQuery. Once you have the results, you can copy them to the POCO objects you want to pass back up manually or using Automapper and a custom profile.

Comment: Wouldn't that result in an a fairly expensive operation and I found this link https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/233 and I'm not sure this feature is implemented yet. It's so frustrating working with this EDMX file

Comment: Yes, my last suggestion is rather inefficient, but if you insist on not modifying the EDMX or your class you have to utilize whatever workaround you can find. The seemingly best option is to import the stored procedure as a function into your EDMX file. BTW, that link you referenced above is the same one I read which indicates SqlQuery does not honor the "column" attribute :)

Comment: At this point I'd rather have a messed up naming convention than using the designer for pulling in stored procedures. There are many times when EF can't figure out what columns are being returned and our database admins have to use hacks to get it to work. Needless to say they really don't like doing this and EF gets a bad reputation because of it. If I can figure out how to use the deeper code, I'd like to manually map the columns to an alias or hopefully this will be a feature in a future release.

Comment: @Halcyon EF uses reflection to map back the the entities when you execute a SP this way.  The easiest way is to alias your SP columns to match the name of your properties in your POCO.  EG SP returns column `MyColumnA` then you should have a property in your POCO that is `MyColumnA`.

Comment: The problem I have is that the developers are not allowed to touch the database. This means we have to map our objects to the DBA's naming convention, which doesn't match our business logic or our naming conventions in a lot of instances. I've been mapping to POCOs that match the results set and then if the columns are are poorly named, I use a second object and map to that. I wish EF had something easy like an alias attribute, which OrmLite has.